# How to convert this date format to PHP

Tags: php, .net

From the JSON snippet that i got from a `.net` API query, I can't seem to convert the date `/Date(1393477200000)/` properly in PHP.

I tried to do `echo date('m/n/Y','1393477200000');` but it is still outputting the wrong date which is `07/7/46127` instead of the correct date of `2/27/2014`.

```
Array
(
    [status] => ok
    [results] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [PROJECT_ID] => 1
                    [COMPANY_ID] => 1
                    [PROJECT_NAME] => The "Getting Started" Project
                    [PROJECT_NUMBER] => 000001
                    [CAN_OPEN_PROJECT] => 1
                    [DATE_START_DATE] => /Date(1393477200000)/
                    [DATE_END_DATE] => /Date(1440648000000)/
                    [PROJECT_DESC] => 
                    [TASK_NUMBER] => 6
                    [DATE_CREATED] => /Date(1409142925980)/
                    [TOTAL_TASKS] => 1
                    [TOTAL_INCOMPLETE_TASKS] => 1
                    [TOTAL_COMPLETED_TASKS] => 0
```

Any ideas how to format `[DATE_START_DATE]` correctly in PHP? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divide your unix-timestamp by 1000, then use date(..).

```
$date = '1393477200000';
echo date("m/d/y", $date/1000);
```

Its that simple.

Result:

> 02/27/14

Comment: Glad I was able to help. Mark as answered, can be closed therefore.

Answer (score 0):

The time received is in milliseconds... You have to divide by a thousand to retrieve UNIX epoch time:

```
echo date('m/d/Y',(1393477200000/1000));
```

And here is the **[fiddle](http://ideone.com/aGbdkg)**

Comment: thanks! seems correct but still short of 25 days though. it output `02/2/2014` but the correct date should be `2/27/2014`.

Comment: I have updated the answer and added a 'fiddle' so you can see the output for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

echo date('m/d/Y',(1393477200000/1000)); U have to truncate last 3 digit.